# How to make Views sorting case-sensitive?

Tags: 7, views

Ascending alphabetical sorting in a Views string field works like this:

```
1
2
3
a
A
b
B
```

But I want it like this:

```
1
2
3
A
B
a
b
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What you're want to do is a sort by a character's byte value. MySQL has a function for this, `BINARY()`, which you could use in your `ORDER BY` criteria (e.g. `ORDER by BINARY(title)`).

Drupal Views doesn't have any default sorting handlers that use this function, so the only way to do it in views is by creating your own custom sort handler.